# Spring Boot Tiles - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tiles

I am trying to configure `Spring Boot 1.4.3` and `Apache tiles 3`.  Using the configuration below I am getting:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils

When I look at the MavenDependencis the jar file `commons-beanutils-1.9.3` containing MethodUtils class is there !
but why embedded `tomcat8.5.6` can not see it?

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.boot.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Boot-RSSReader</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring-Boot-RSSReader</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ConfigForTiles:**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigForTiles {

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer(){
        final TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions(new String [] {"WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml"});
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver(){
        final TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**mvn dependency:tree**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:3.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have multiple versions of `commons-beanutils` in your classpath.

In your IDE you can search for `commons-beanutils` - you should be able to find multiple versions of `commons-beanutils`.

Maven commands that can help you debugging this:

```
mvn dependency:tree
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Try excluding `commons-beanutils` from `org.apache.tiles`, as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am using STS 3.8.3 there is only one version of commons-beanutils in the classpath

Comment: Excluding commons-beanutils from org.apache.tiles did not help  I get the error message : NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: I had multiple versions of commons-beanutils in my Maven repository in C:\Documents and Settings\user1\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\      I kept 1.9.3 and deleted the rest and now everything is O.K. !!

Comment: that's what I was telling you.